# Is SharePoint Designer freeware?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am working on SharePoint 2013. I want to design some forms for my site. For this I need to install SharePoint Designer 2013, but before install I need to know if SharePoint designer 2013 is a freeware or if I need to buy licence?

Comment: You should google first before creating a new post. First hit on google: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491. Look at the very first sentence on this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Designer 2013 is free to install and use.

Doesn't cost you anything except you need to have SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SharePoint Designer 2013 is absolutely free. You don't need any license to install and use it.

However, you will need SharePoint site and valid credentials.

You can download SharePoint Designer 2013 on Microsoft site. See following link:

[SharePoint Designer 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491).